# Turtlebot Create Issues on Groovy

Tags: ros, irobot-create, turtlebot, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently having issues getting my Turtlebot 1 (using iRobot Create) working using a fresh install of Groovy. Previously I've been running fine on Fuerte.

I'm aware there's been a fair amount of change in the implementation for Groovy, so I'd like to know whether others have this working currently, or if it is a work in progress.

The 2 initial issues I ran into were:

1. References from turtlebot_node.py & create_sensor_handler.py still made to "turtlebot_driver" which now looks to be renamed to "create_driver" - solved by renaming import
2. create_node unable to resolve PyKDL import - solved by adding kdl dependency to manifest

I've moved past both of those issues - now I receive a Exception: Robot not connected, SCI not available, despite the create connecting successfully with its state visible on the turtlebot dashboard.

If others have their Turtlebots working on Groovy I'd be interested whether you needed any changes beyond the configuration items in the tutorials

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54856/turtlebot-create-issues-on-groovy/) by [MarkStodden](https://answers.ros.org/users/1800/markstodden/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2013-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is currently no support for the original Turltlebot in Groovy.  For now, Groovy only supports the new Kobuki-based Turtlebot. There are plans to add support for the original Turtlebot in the not-too-distant future, but for now your best bet is probably Fuerte.  You can follow some of the discussion at the Turtlebot SIG:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ros-sig-turtlebot

Groovy also doesn't yet have support for the Turtlebot simulator.

---

Originally posted by [nsprague](https://answers.ros.org/users/2815/nsprague/) with karma: 228 on 2013-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkStodden](https://answers.ros.org/users/1800/markstodden/) on 2013-02-12**:
Thanks for the response, and for the link to the forum